# Firebase auth ui or google sign in on macOS and iOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos, firebase-authentication, google-signin

The firebase documentation only tells you how you can sign in on ios, but it seems that firebase UI and googleSignIn don't work on macOS, and pod install gives a warning about how it's not compatible.

Does anyone know a way to sign into firebase that still has the same code for iOS and macOS?

I know that you can sign in to google and then sign in to firebase with the firebase custom sign-in, but wouldn't that create a separate account that's not the google account? I have a website where people signed in with Google, and if I do it that way they wouldn't have the same account.

Comment: This issue might be related: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46157